# Bridge wireless connection from OSX 10.8 to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, networking, macosx, network-bridge

I have a Mac running OSX 10.8.2 that is connected to a wireless network. My Ubuntu 12.04 LTS box has no internet capability atm (wired network down). I would like to bridge the connection on my Mac such that I can access the internet via my Ubuntu box. I have a flash drive to get software from the Mac to the Ubuntu box if necessary.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can bridge the wireless connection to the wired connection on the mac system.
Then you connect both pcs by an ethernet cable. If at least one system has GbE, you don't need a crossover cable.

I think it will be much easier to buy an 10€ usb wifi connector. Watch out for Linux compatibility.

Comment: If it helped, please set as solution. If not, you could have asked...